# request animation frame resetting an incremented variable each loop

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I am trying to rotate an image on HTML canvas by 40, 1 degree at a time as part of a request animation frame loop. However, once ran, the amount the image rotates changes seemingly randomly on every refresh of the page, occasionally working exactly how I want it. Upon debugging, the 'counter' variable appears to be resetting each loop, despite being incremented. I'm at a loss as to what could cause this, new to the language, any help would be appreciated.

```
  let counter = 0;  //sets counter to 0

requestAnimationFrame(spin)  //initialises the loop

function spin(){

    rc.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    rc.save();
    rc.translate(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);       //translates canvas for rotation (rc is canvas context)
    const angle = -1;     //angle to rotate by each loop
    rc.rotate(radCalc(angle));      //actual rotation (function is angle * PI/180)

    counter++  //Counter should keep track of each loop, yet resets every time?

    rc.translate(-frameWidth/2, -frameHeight/2)   //restore canvas
    rc.drawImage(dialSpinImage, column * frameWidth, row *frameHeight, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight )   //draw image
    rc.restore

    let stop = requestAnimationFrame(spin);  //get animation frame ID

    if (counter < 40){   //checks canvas has not rotated over 40 degrees

        requestAnimationFrame(spin)

    }

    else {    //if it has, stop the loop

        cancelAnimationFrame(stop)

    }

}
```

}

Comment: rc.restore **()** you don't call that method currently, so all your transforms are adding to the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks! So I should call it outside the loop?

Comment: What? No, in your loop you have a line `rc.restore`, make it `rc.restore();`.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread the message, thanks!

Comment: Having tried this, it no longer loops, so the image moves one degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of smaller errors in your code. Let's get through all of 'em:

## 1

Inside the function `spin()` is the following line:

```
const angle = -1;
```

This ultimately resets angle to -1 with every invocation of spin(). The variable needs to be defined outside the scope of the function and just decremented inside.

## 2

```
let stop = requestAnimationFrame(spin);  //get animation frame ID

if (counter < 40){   //checks canvas has not rotated over 40 degrees

    requestAnimationFrame(spin)

}
```

This doesn't work like you might expect. The first line doesn't just return a frame ID you might eventually use - no - it calls the requested function spin() right away. Like the angle variable it needs to be defined once outside the function.

With all of the above in mind, here's a working example of your code:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let rc = canvas.getContext("2d");
let dialSpinImage = new Image();
let frameWidth = canvas.width;
let frameHeight = canvas.height;
let angle = 0;
let reqAnim;
let counter = 0;

dialSpinImage.onload = function() {
  start();
}
dialSpinImage.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/60/60";

function start() {
  reqAnim = requestAnimationFrame(spin);
}

function spin() {
  rc.clearRect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
  rc.save();
  rc.translate(frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2); //translates canvas for rotation (rc is canvas context)
  angle -= 1;
  rc.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  counter++;


  rc.translate(-frameWidth / 2, -frameHeight / 2) //restore canvas
  rc.drawImage(dialSpinImage, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight) //draw image
  rc.restore();



  if (counter < 40) { //checks canvas has not rotated over 40 degrees

    reqAnim = requestAnimationFrame(spin)

  } else { //if it has, stop the loop

    cancelAnimationFrame(reqAnim);
 
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```